# TreeView based on ObservableList gives undesirable result

Tags: javafx, treeview, observable, listener

An ObservableList obList has a listener, upon addition it updates the TreeView. As new string "music" is added to obList, new item is created and put in the tree view. The item renders as "{ [music] added at 0 }" instead of expected "music".

```
TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem();
root.setExpanded(true);
TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView(root);
treeView.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>("cat")); // normal behaviour
obList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
obList.addListener(new ListChangeListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends String> c) {
        while (c.next()) {
            if (c.wasAdded()) {
                TreeItem<String> temp = new TreeItem(c);
                tree.getRoot().getChildren().add(temp);
            }  
        }
});

obList.add("music");
```

It seems that variable c contains string and extra information. What is going on and what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't use the raw type, the compiler would have complained about the issue.

You set the value to the `ListChangeListener.Change` object instead of a `String` in the following line. Using the raw type on the right hand side removes the type check that would have resulted in a compile time error.

```
TreeItem<String> temp = new TreeItem(c);
```

Instead iterate through the list of added items and add a `TreeItem` for all of them:

```
while (c.next()) {
    if (c.wasAdded()) {
        for (String element : c.getAddedSubList()) {
            TreeItem<String> temp = new TreeItem<>(element);
            tree.getRoot().getChildren().add(temp);
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it with:

```
obList.getAddedSubList().forEach(l ->
    TreeItem<String> temp = new TreeItem(l);
    tree.getRoot().getChildren().add(temp);
});
```